# My hydraulic MTB brakes squeal after I cleaned my bike

Tags: brakes

My hydraulic MTB brakes stated to squeal after I washed my bike why?

Comment: What did you use to clean it? Some cleaning solutions can leave a residue that can cause disc brakes to squeal.

Comment: The disk brakes on my 2001 Honda would squeak badly after a rain.  Oxide builds up on the disks and must be rubbed off to eliminate the squeaks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you re-lube your chain after you cleaned the bike? If I am not careful when I lube the chain on my mountainbike I get some splatter and if it gets on the brake pads I get loud braking for a while, louder when wet.

Now, I slowly lube my chain while turning cranks backwards, key is slowly, both to get every linkage and not splatter lube. Then I continue to spin backwards slowly for 30-40 seconds, let is set for 5 minutes and use a rag to wipe any excess from the chain so it doesn't splatter once I get going.

Comment: A clean rag and some brake cleaner or alcohol after cleaning can help too.